# Capybara - have_css matches empty string when it's supposed not to

Tags: ruby, selenium, testing, rspec, capybara

New at Capybara. Testing the following piece of code. value can be dynamic, including "" (empty).

```rb
within("#foo") do
  expect(page).to have_css("td:nth-child(2)", text: value)
end
```

The problem is: when value = "", even when there is text in td:nth-child(2) it matches as true.
Possible reason: the content is rendered async and when Capybara checks for the first time, the text is no yet there (that means, ""), so it is true.

Any way of only matching true only when the text is indeed empty at the end, and false when it is not empty?

Answer (score 1):

By default Capybaras `text` parameter does substring matches so "" will match any text contents (since "" is a substring of everything).  If you want an exact match then you need to do either

```
expect(page).to have_css("td:nth-child(2)", text: value, exact_text: true)
```

or more concisely

```
expect(page).to have_css("td:nth-child(2)", exact_text: value)
```

Comment: expect(page).to have_css("td:nth-child(2)", text: value, exact_text: true)  
This helped me in a doubt I had and if I have to validate different texts for example ACTIVE AND INACTIVE?